# How to create a js file for wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to create custom js work for a wordpress site. how do I make a .js document with the relevant coding for my site? trying with TextEdit isn't working

Comment: "trying with TextEdit isn't working" what does this mean?

Comment: Create a new file with a `.js` file extension

Comment: JavaScript files are just plain text files with the `.js` extension. You don't need an IDE to write one, you can write one simply using notepad or similar. I don't use wordpress. I'm using blogspot myself but I assume the process is similar, in that after you created your file you can upload it to either your wordpress host or your own host and reference it in one of the wordpress templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a theme? You should have a directory inside your theme directory called `js/`, `javascripts/`, or something like that. To get a javascript file included on your wordpress site, you should make a file in there and name it anything you like, just make sure it has a .js file extension. For example, let's name it `custom.js`.

Once you do that, you need to tell WordPress to load that javascript file. The instructions are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), but the way to do it is to find the `functions.php` file located in the root directory of your theme, and add this code:

```
function my_custom_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_javascript' );
```

Wordpress will automatically look in your template directory (`get_template_directory_uri()`) and will 'enqueue', or queue up, the javascript file you tell it to -- in this case, custom.js

To check and see if this file is being included, you can put this code inside your `custom.js` file:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert( "Here's your javascript!" );
});
```

If you reload your WordPress page on the front end, you should see an alert with that message.